# C # API React-Native callback

Tags: c#, axios

I have a C# API project. The web side of the project is finished and now I've moved on to the mobile side. I'm getting an error when sending a request to the API in React Native. I have a graduation project and I need to provide an API connection, can you help me?

[image]

Here I share the C# startup side:

```cs
using Businnes.Abstract;
using Businnes.Concrete;
using DataAccess.Abstract;
using DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFrameWork;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IUserDal, EfUserDal>();

            services.AddSingleton<IPoemService, PoemManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPoemDal, EfPoemDal>();

            services.AddSingleton<IPoemScoreService, PoemScoreManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPoemScoreDal, EfPoemScoreDal>();

            services.AddSingleton<IPoemGetScoreService, PoemGetScoreManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPoemGetScoreDal, EfPoemGetScoreDal>();

            services.AddSingleton<IPunishmentService, PunishmentManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPunishmentDal, EfPunishmentDal>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
                
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried most things on the page but none of them worked.

Comment: You are using CORS middleware but haven't added it to your services. Try adding this line in your ConfigureServices: services.AddCors();

Comment: Can you fetch the contents of `localhost:44386` using cURL?